# Creating new files from multiple files that have been scanned and manipulated in powershell

Tags: powershell

First of all, I'm a complete newbie at Powershell.
I've basically compiled a script from a number google search results and it works to a certain degree, so be gentle :)

I have a number of large plain text files that need scanning, junk data needs removing, and characters need renaming. Then create a new file in the same directory

Here is the script I have for individual files, I have replaced actual keywords for something unrelated, but for testing purposes you should see what I am trying to achieve:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Tomatoes-2022-09-27.txt |
    Where-Object { - $_.Contains('red') } |            # Keeping only lines containing "red"
    Foreach {$_ -replace "[/()]",":"}|                 # replacing specific characters to a colon
    Where-Object { -not $_.Contains('too red') } |     # removing lines containing "too red"
Set-Content C:\Temp\Tomatoes-2022-09-27Ripe.txt        # saving as a new file *Ripe.txt
```

This works for individual files just fine but what I need to do is the same process for any file within the Temp directory.
They all have similar names other than the date.

Here's what I have compiled for all files, but it overwrites existing files rather than creating a new one and I don't know how to get it to write to new files ie Tomotoes*Ripe.txt:  *being the unique date

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.* -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    (Get-Content $_) | 
    Where-Object { - $_.Contains('red') } |  
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "[/()]", ":" } | 
    Where-Object { -not $_.Contains('too red') } | 
    Set-Content $_ 
}
```

Or will it be better to create a copy first using New-Item then process the other jobs?

It's going to be something very simple I know! And will most definitely kick myself once corrected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a sample input file and the desired output?

Comment: Hi Mathias, the first script on the post is an example for each file. The only thing that changes for each file is the date. The contents is irrelevant as all filtering and data removal is fine, I've included a reason for each to the right of the script. It's just saving a copy of the original files to new filename "for all" is where I'm stuck. I basically need to save a copy for Tomatoes-2022-09-01.txt, Tomatoes-2022-09-02.txt,  Tomatoes-2022-09-03.txt etc to Tomatoes-2022-09-01ripe.txt, Tomatoes-2022-09-02ripe.txt, Tomatoes-2022-09-03ripe.txt. Ideally to process each file in a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you want is something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    $newFile    = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ('{0}Ripe{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
    $newContent = Get-Content $_.FullName | 
                  Where-Object { $_ -like '*red*' -and $_ -notlike '*too red*' } |  
                  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "[/()]", ":" } 
    $newContent | Set-Content -Path $newFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74475975/45375) - which is probably the most straightforward in your case - with a streaming, single-pipeline solution that showcases two advanced techniques:

- the [common `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable), which allows you to store a cmdlet's current pipeline output object in a self-chosen variable that can be referenced later in a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) in a later pipeline segment.
- [delay-bind script blocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), which allow you to use a script block to dynamically determine a parameter value, typically based on the pipeline input object at hand; in this case, the pipeline *variable* is used.

```bash
# Create sample files
'red1' > t1.txt
'red2' > t2.txt

Get-ChildItem -PipelineVariable file t?.txt | # note `-PipelineVariable file`
  Get-Content |                               # read file line by line
  Where-Object { $_.Contains('red') } |       # sample filter
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'e', '3' } |   # sample transformation
  Set-Content -LiteralPath {                  # delay-bind script block
    # Determine the output file name based on pipelinve variable $file
    '{0}Ripe{1}' -f $file.BaseName, $file.Extension 
  }
```

This results in files `t1Ripe.txt` and `t2Ripe.txt`, containing `r3d1` and `r3d2`, respectively.